# Azure api management SOAP-To-REST

Tags: rest, api, azure, soap, azure-api-management

I am using API management to convert my `SOAP` services into `REST`. The SOAP services are accessible only using ip adress not with machine name, but when I imported SOAP service in the API management it took the machine name and i changed it to ip address in the Settings tab in the Publisher portal.

When i try to call the REST endpoint of the SOAP service from developer portal, it is somehow taking the machine name and forming the request with the machine name itself. I have provided the Trace of my request below. In the backend section i see `newBackendServiceUrl` is changed to machine name. How to override `newBackendServiceUrl` so that it takes the ip adress instead of machine name. 
set-backend-service (0 ms)

```
{
    "message": "Backend service URL was changed.",
    "oldBackendServiceUrl": "ipaddress:2008/",
    "newBackendServiceUrl": "machine-name:2008/",
    "request": {
        "url": "machine-name:2008/CL1LCTRY/CLLCTRYS_COUNTRY_LIST"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the newBackendServiceUrl by adding "Set backend service" policy at the API scope. 
For example: set-backend-service base-url="http://ip-address:2008"

Comment: With SOAP to REST a special policy is generated to do transformation. So there is no need to add an extra policy, you should be able to find set-backend policy and just change/remove it.